# Bar Chart Example D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Ive been fiddling around with this for the past hour, but I don't understand why this example does not run. All I did was copy and paste the code. I've tried replicating this example in the format of previous tutorials but there is no difference.

The Tutorial is : http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-1.html

My copy and paste code : http://jsfiddle.net/2ga27/2/

Note, I skipped to the SVG section
`.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A look at the [console in Google Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) indicates the problem:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

The same error can be seen in Firefox on the [Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console).

After defining data this way (as shown in the example):

```js
var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];
```

[the jsFiddle works](http://jsfiddle.net/2ga27/3/).

Comment: thank you especially for the debugging tip; shall use that from now on